# find the text inside a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I couldn't figure out a way to get the text inside the element with "td" tag and "fc-bi-regcode-value" class
here is how the html looks like :

```
<td class="fc-bi-regcode-value">74000234</td>
```

want the 74000234 code
can anyone please help

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,"html.parser")
xx=soup.find("td",class_="fc-bi-regcode-value")
regcode.append(xx.text)
```

Comment: can you share your url?

Comment: Does your code not work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: if you just `print(xx.text)` what value are you getting?

Comment: @abdusco I'm getting an empty list

Comment: @KunduK here you go : https://www.neti.ee/visiitkaart/74000234

Comment: @Kloe90 : If you `print(soup) ` and check the value it is showing following columns EMPTY.that is why you are getting `empty list`. JavaScripts rendering the page here.You could use selenium to load the page and then beautifulsoup to fetch the value.

Comment: okay I will try that now

Answer (score 0):

That table does not exist on the page, it's loaded via an AJAX request from this url: `https://www.neti.ee/api/BusinessDirectory/get?ixRegCode=74000234`

You need to make that request yourself and use the JSON

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://www.neti.ee/api/BusinessDirectory/get?ixRegCode=74000234'
data = requests.get(url).json()
reg_code = data['org']['regcode']
pprint(reg_code)
```

output:

```
'74000234'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API which returns result in json() format.

```
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
rseponse=requests.get("https://www.neti.ee/api/BusinessDirectory/get?ixRegCode=74000234",headers=headers).json()
print(rseponse['org']['regcode'])
```